# g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘d21’: execvp: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: compiler-errors, c++17, g++, execvp

When I try to compile a QT project it gives this error:
g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘d21’: execvp: No such file or directory
I have also tried to include full path of file while compiling but same error occured. Just to be sure of version mismatch I looked for both gcc and g++ version but both are same, gcc/g++ version: 9.4.0.

When I try to compile a QT project it gives this error:
g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘d21’: execvp: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

d21 is the D programming language GCC driver. You need to install GDC, D programming language support in GCC.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error myself when building an application with the `cmake` Ninja generator.  A variable preceding `DEP_FILE` had a newline in its string value, which caused `gcc` to try and treat the dependency file as if it was a D source file.

The fix for me was to add `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` to the `execute_process` command that was generating the problematic variable in `cmake`.

I would suggest inspecting generated build files like `build.ninja` (if you're using the Ninja generator) to see if you're getting a similar problem.  Or it may be obvious from the command-line that generates the error that some corruption of variables is going on.

You may also find that the issue goes away if you use a different `cmake` generator (assuming that you're building a `cmake` project).